# Helper to call close() if implements AutoCloseable?

Tags: java, autocloseable

Is there any helper method in the JDK or common libraries that does this:

```
if (resource instanceof AutoCloseable) {
    ((AutoCloseable) resource).close();
}
```

Just a one-liner to call an object's `close()` if applicable.

I know about try-with-resources, that's not applicable to this situation.  And I know that not all classes that have a `close()` method implement `AutoCloseable`.  But, I seem to write the above over and over..

Comment: That looks like a XY problem. Can you tell more about the context? You should not have to use `instanceof`.

Comment: fge: yes a clarification is in order: I have a ref to an interface, at compile time I can't know if the impl also implements AutoCloseable in addition to the interface.

Comment: Uhm, yes you can: `public <T extends YourInterface & AutoCloseable> void doSomethingWith(T victim)`

Comment: That would restrict to AutoCloseable impls; I'm looking to ".. call an object's close() *if applicable* ".

Comment: That really doesn't look right at all. There is something fundamentally wrong with this approach, you should explain your problem more.

Comment: I don't get it. You shouldn't have code that closes resources it didn't allocate. Resource-allocating code should use an ARM block.

Answer (score 0):

There's something Apache Commons offers:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#closeQuietly(java.io.Closeable)

Comment: Doesn't help. For one, there is no requirement that an `AutoCloseable` also implements `Closeable`. And second, this utility pales in comparison to Guava's `Closer`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is apache commons `closeQuietly` adapted for AutoCloseable:

```
  static void closeQuietly(AutoCloseable closeable) {
    try {
      if (closeable != null) {
        closeable.close();
      }
    }
    catch (Exception swallowed) {
    }
  }
```

since google sent me here for that case :)

Answer (score -1):

**Edit**:

Check this:

```
class CloserHelper
{
    public static void close(Object object)
    {
        if (object instanceof AutoCloseable)
        {
            try
            {
                ((AutoCloseable) object).close();
            }
            catch (Exception ignored) { }
        }
    }
}
```

---

I can think to something like this

```
class CloserHelper
{
    public static void close(AutoCloseable obj) throws Exception
    {
        obj.close();
    }
}
```

Then

```
CloserHelper.close(resource);
```

If the object is not a `AutoCloseable` you cannot just call it

---

If you want to ignore exceptions

```
class CloserHelper
{
    public static void close(AutoCloseable obj)
    {
        try
        {
            obj.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Marco: I have a ref to an interface, at compile time I can't know if the impl also implements AutoCloseable in addition to the interface.

Comment: `catch (Exception e)` <-- bad. You also catch all unchecked exceptions with that. And that includes `NullPointerEception`.

Comment: @fge Yes, my code want to ignore all exceptions. Anyway instanceof will avoid null so no NullPointerException